# Error CS1061 On accessing a List of objects in another object, within the same namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a structure of objects that I am trying to access in order to populate. Im not using any directive aliases just to make sure I can get it all working first, but for some reason my foreach loop cannot access my list of objects, contained in another object.

Here is the error : 
**CS1061    'List' does not contain a definition for 'entitlements' and no extension method 'entitlements' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

And here is where the error is being triggered (second foreach loop, on "entitlements" ) :

```
foreach (EntitlementGroup eg in report.product.context.productDetails.entitlementgroup)
             {
                writer.WriteStartElement("EntitlementGroup");
                foreach (Entitlement e in report.product.context.productDetails.entitlementgroup.entitlements)
                   { 
                            //do stuff}
                   }
              }
```

The error is coming from the second foreach loop, on entitlements. Ill put the entitlements and entitlementgroup classes here :

**EntitlementGroup**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace XMLWriter
{
    public class EntitlementGroup
    {

        public List<Entitlement> entitlements { get; set; }
        public EntitlementGroup(List<Entitlement> entitlements)
        {
            this.entitlements = entitlements;
        }
    }
}
```

**Entitlement**

```
using System.Linq;
namespace XMLWriter
{
    public class Entitlement
    {
        public string primaryIndicator { get; set; }
        public string includeExcludeIndicator { get; set; }
        public AudienceTypeEntitlement audienceTypeEntitlement { get; set; }
        public Entitlement(string primaryIndicator, string includeExcludeIndicator, AudienceTypeEntitlement audienceTypeEntitlement)
        {
            this.primaryIndicator = primaryIndicator;
            this.includeExcludeIndicator = includeExcludeIndicator;
            this.audienceTypeEntitlement = audienceTypeEntitlement;
        }
    }
}
```

it seems to me that the class can see all the other objects (productdetails, context, etc) just fine based on previous method implementations

Comment: What is the type of `report.product.context.productDetails.entitlementgroup`?  It isn't an `EntitlementGroup`, it's a list.  and lists don't have a property `entitlements`.

Comment: you should be accessing attributes of `e` variable inside your nested loop, and also, nested loop should make use of the `eg` variable

Comment: @Will Debugging comes after successful compilation. This snippet won't even compile.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Hah!  Good point.

Comment: @Wil  I appreciate the feedback, I'm new to C#. Don't really understand the downvotes for asking this question. TanveerBadar and ironstone13 answered the question perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
foreach (EntitlementGroup eg in report.product.context.productDetails.entitlementgroup)
 {
    writer.WriteStartElement("EntitlementGroup");
    foreach (Entitlement e in eg.entitlements)
       { 
                //do stuff}
       }
  }
```